# Hide rows with an inputbox integer starting range

Tags: vba, excel

What I want to do is have a command button, that when pressed, pops up an inputbox asking for "Please enter number of items (Limit 5000)", then runs a VBA code that hides all rows between Inputbox.value + 3(the number of header rows) to row 5003 (the end of the sheet).

I have found the below code which lets me hide columns using a toggle button

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
     Dim xAddress As String
         xAddress = "BV:CQ"
    If ToggleButton1.Value Then

    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = True
    Else
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Im unsure how exactly to create an inputbox, and then adjust that number to account for the headers, then to set that as the starting row for the range using the above code (changing Columns for Rows in the code).

Answer (score 0):

Below example is for input box

```
N = Application.InputBox("Input a number", Type:=1)
'Type:=0 A formula
'Type:=1 A number
'Type:=2 Text (a string)
'Type:=4 A logical value (True or False)
'Type:=8 A cell reference, as a Range object
'Type:=16 An error value, such as #N/A
'Type:=64 An array of values
```

But think you may create a logic auto detect the length of your record

Using below function,

nLastRow will be 3, if Column A have nothing.

```
nLastRow = getLastRow(Sheets(1).Range("A:A"), 3)

Function getLastRow(ByVal inputRng As Range, ByVal headerRow As Single) As Single
Dim nRow As Single
    nRow = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    nRow = inputRng.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    If nRow = 0 Or nRow <= headerRow Then
        nRow = headerRow
    End If
    getLastRow = nRow
End Function
```

Hope this help !